# How To access Inter Json Object Object value

Tags: javascript, json

How I can access the value of location address from this json Object.

How to get values from string

```
{
    "total": 1494,
    "businesses": [
        {
            "price": "$$",
            "phone": "+19055222999",
            "name": "Earth To Table : Bread Bar",
            "url": "https://www.yelp.com/biz/earth-to-table-bread-bar-hamilton?adjust_creative=o3c6gGE-jHIf_ycxKdETJA&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_search&utm_source=o3c6gGE-jHIf_ycxKdETJA",
            "location": {
                "address1": "Mars",
                "city": "Toronto",
                "address3": "",
                "address2": "",
                "state": "ON",
                "country": "CA"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tried `

```
str = JSON.parse(string.businesses.location[0]);
```

But it returns **string.businesses.location is not a function**

Comment: `str = JSON.parse(string).businesses[0].location;`

Comment: Alexander, you see how `businesses` is an array accessed by a zero-based index? You can iterate this array with a loop such as `for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) { businesses[i].location };`

Comment: `someArray.slice(0,5)`

Comment: @Pointy you can write your answer and I will mark it correct!

Comment: @Alexander it's OK somebody got it - I was on the phone and couldn't really type :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to convert the JSON string to a JSON Object first and then try to access the data.

```
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
var location = jsonObj.businesses[0].location;
```

Answer (score -1):

In the JSON, the location doesn't have '[' so is not a list, but the businesses have the '[',so you should change:

```
str = JSON.parse(string.businesses.location[0]);
```

for this

```
//first parse all the json
var dataJson = JSON.parse(string);
//second take te value
var address = dataJson.businesses[0].location.address1
```

[Check the example here!!!](https://jsfiddle.net/xk2erers/4/)